# How to maintain the fragment state in navigation components

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am using navigation components architecture in my project. I have a problem in that.

For example: I have two Fragment A and Fragment B

Fragment A -> Has Recycler view of 50 items

Fragment B -> Show Detail of single item in recycler view of Fragment A

Problem is when user scroll down to last item and click the last item. Here everything works fine

When user click the last item and it moves to fragment B. when he back pressed from fragment B. Fragment A gets recreated. I want to restrict the recreation of Fragment A in navigation component.

I am struck in this situation. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can poke around the Navigation library to force it to hold onto a particular Fragment instance, but you shouldn't be doing that anyway. There's no way for you to guarantee that object will stay in memory, especially if you move away from the app and come back.

Instead, you need to design your app so it'll restore its state, and put everything back the way it was. A lot of the UI components already do this for you (e.g. an `EditText` will remember what the user has typed in it).

A `RecyclerView` will remember where it was scrolled to, but if you need to fetch data for the adapter, you'll probably want to set this:

```
adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```

That will make it hold off restoring the scroll until your adapter has more than zero items (otherwise it'll just "scroll" to the top and you'll lose your place)

If you have any other state you need to save (e.g. something identifying which set of data you're currently looking at, so you know what you need to fetch) [you need to persist it](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states)